# Hazelcast C++ Client

Tags: hazelcast

I'm trying using hazelcast-3.6 with hazelcast-cpp-client-3.6.
I downloaded both packages and created an empty C++ application which currently just includes HazelcastAll.h.

During build I get errors for missing files which indeed are missing from downloaded official c++ client (i.e. MapExecuteOnKeyCodec.h).

Did anyone encounter such issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some required files are in `hazelcast\generated-sources\`. E.g. [`MapExecuteOnKeyCodec.h` is in `hazelcast\generated-sources\include\hazelcast\client\protocol\codec`](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-cpp-client/blob/master/hazelcast/generated-sources/include/hazelcast/client/protocol/codec/MapExecuteOnKeyCodec.h). You have to add `hazelcast\generated-sources\include\` to the additional include directories.